# How do I mark a mousewheel event as passive in Vue js?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, passive-event-listeners

Chrome is warning me that I have: "Added a non-passive event listener to a scroll-blocking 'mousewheel' event".

I want that warning to go away. I'm using Vue js 2.5.13 and according to the [documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Event-Modifiers%20documentation), you can use `<div v-on:scroll.passive="onScroll">...</div>` to make events passive. However, I cannot figure it out for a mousewheel event.

Here is my code:

```
<select v-model='selectWatcher'>
    <option v-for="option in myOptions" v-bind:value="option.id">{{option.name}}</option>
</select>
```

If it helps, `selectWatcher`, is a function within my vue instance's watch section.

I have tried:

`<select v-model='selectWatcher' v-on:mousewheel.passive>`

`<select v-model='selectWatcher' v-on:mousewheel.passive="true">`

`<select v-model='selectWatcher' v-on:scroll.passive="mousewheel">`

None of this works, and I still get the warning. What am I doing wrong? Do I need to mark the `selectWatcher` as passive somehow?

Comment: The `.passive` event modifier is [new in 2.3.0+](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Event-Modifiers)

Comment: Yes, and I am using vue 2.5

Comment: The code you included doesn't have a `v-on:mousewheel`, so it isn't clear where the error is being generated. FWIW, only the last of the `v-on`s that you tried is correctly structured.

Comment: I don't specifically use the mousewheel event anywhere in my code, but that is the event Chrome warns about. It happens each time I click a select box with a `v-model`

Comment: Sounds like it's a Vue-internal event associated with the `select`, in which case I don't think there's anything you can do. I trust `selectWatcher` is also a data item or prop?

Comment: `selectWatcher` is a watch property

Answer (score 0):

Since you're not creating a `mousewheel` event, you won't be able to modify the event it's complaining about. There's no way to say "make all mousewheel events passive".

Comment: I wasn't clear in my comment before. The `selectWatcher` in my example above is data. It has a matching watch function that runs when the `selectWatcher` data array changes